# Postgres complains about geometry type doesn't exist during docker startup, then decides it exists later

Tags: postgresql, docker, postgis

I'm trying to use a PostGIS geometry column with a docker build.
When docker starts up the container I get the following logs (abbreviated for clarity):

```
Loading PostGIS extensions into template_postgis
CREATE EXTENSION
CREATE EXTENSION
CREATE EXTENSION
CREATE EXTENSION
Loading PostGIS extensions into postgres
CREATE EXTENSION
CREATE EXTENSION
CREATE EXTENSION
CREATE EXTENSION
/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/script.sql
```

where script.sql contains the following:

```
CREATE TABLE public.spatial_data_wfs (
  id int4 NOT NULL,
  name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  featureid varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  geofeature jsonb NOT NULL,
  coordinates geometry NOT NULL
);
```

Despite loading the PostGIS extensions before the script, it gives the following error:

```
psql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/script.sql:238: ERROR:  type "geometry" does not exist
LINE 6:  coordinates geometry NOT NULL,
```

If I remove the geometry column and wait for the container to start up, I can use an alter table statement to add the geometry column, and it works fine.

The script also defines a function that generates a polygon, which doesn't pose any problem. I have tried the following based on other SO questions:

1. Create the postgis extension: complains it has already been created.
2. Use ALTER DATABASE to SET search_path TO include postgis. No complaint, same problem.

I can only assume the following from the logs:

1. There is some order of operations problem where despite the fact that postgis is installed, I still can't use a geometry column because something else has to complete first. Whatever it is, it has completed by the time postgres accepts connections.
2. The function is only validated for syntax - the fact the function code refers to the geometry type in the function body doesn't matter until someone calls it.

Has anyone else seen this? We're expecting all our stuff to build using Docker and Jenkins.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the problem. The database script was originally created by some tool (I think it might be pgdump) and then manual changes were added. The tool that adds a bunch of statements to the beginning of the script that aren't really necessary. One of those statements is the following:

```
SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false);
```

I guess this setting overrides "ALTER DATABASE to SET search_path". Once I removed that statement, the script works fine, and the table is created.